# Cannot get juju works with OpenStack Juno

Tags: juju, openstack

I am trying to use `juju` to work with OpenStack Juno but failed. The version of juju is `1.22.0-trusty-amd64`. The VM is running and I can `ssh` into it, update / upgrade. Below is the steps I followed:

```
glance image-create .... ; this step works well and give out an image ID
juju metadata generate-image ... -d ./jujuopenstack ; this step works well
juju metadata generate-tools .. -d ./jujuopenstack ; this step works well
juju bootstrap --debug --metadata-source ./jujuopenstack -v --show-log
```

the last step returns an error

```
Bootstrapping Juju machine agent
Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'init-local' at Fri, 20 Mar 2015 03:31:50 +0000. Up 7.03 seconds.

...

juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:432
    skipping index because of error getting latest metadata
    "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/streams/v1/index.json":
    index file has no data for cloud {regionOne htXXXXXX2.27.0.33:5000/v2.0/} not found
juju.cmd supercommand.go:411 cannot set initial environ constraints:
    index file has no data for cloud {regionOne htXXXXXX2.27.0.33:5000/v2.0/} not found
juju.cmd supercommand.go:411 failed to bootstrap environment:
    subprocess encountered error code 1
```

My question is: where is the index file? Where can I generate or upload it to?

<sup>(also posted on https://github.com/juju/juju/issues/1893)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The metadata commands you used will generate the index and other files. What seems to be the problem is a mismatch between the cloud/region name in those files, and what you have in your juju environments.yaml file. Could you compare them? Specifically the keystone (auth) url needs to match, byte for byte.

Comment: hi andreas ,

https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1435644

the link include all details what I meet .

Comment: I didn't see the index file and other content from that metadata directory in that bug, but maybe I missed it. Anyway, seems like the juju team is helping you out there.