# A dead lock cycle when using juju "sync-tools" command , any tips?

Tags: juju, openstack

all

I want use sync-tools upload  tools for prepare my environment , before I bootstrap it .

If I run sync-tools before bootstrap , the error message is : you environment is not bootstraped .

So , I juju bootstrap my environment , but not successed .

```
(reference:) http://askubuntu.com/questions/598994/juju-can-not-work-with-openstack-juno-trying-for-10-days
```

When I run sync-tools , the error message as below :

```
$  juju  sync-tools  --source="https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools"   --show-log
juju.cmd supercommand.go:37 running juju [1.22.0-trusty-amd64 gc]
juju.provider.openstack provider.go:249 opening environment "openstack"  
juju.api apiclient.go:252 dialing "wss://172.27.0.50:17070/"
juju.api apiclient.go:252 dialing "wss://172.27.0.50:17070/"
juju.api apiclient.go:252 dialing "wss://172.27.0.50:17070/"
```

any tips!

What is the best time for use sync-tools command ? before bootstrap or after bootstrap ?

if after bootstrap , the bootstrap process need tools . so dead lock happend.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. You are clearly having problems before I was, and my answer won't help you.

Your bootstrap machine does not have access to the internet, right?
This is what worked for me.  I named my environment maas, and my bootstrap machine jujuBS.  I made a sub directory under my home called .juju to hold the tools and charms.  I copied what I needed locally and boot strapped and deployed juju-gui:

```
mkdir ~./.juju/sync-tools
juju sync-tools –e maas –destination=”~/.juju/sync-tools”
juju bootstrap –e maas –-upload-tools=true –-metadata-source=”.juju/sync-tools” -–to jujuBS.local
mkdir –p ~/.juju/charms/trusty
juju charm get juju-gui .juju/charms/trusty
juju deploy –repository=”~/.juju/charms” local:juju-gui
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to sync-tools before you bootstrap.  If you can sync during the bootstrap, there is not reason to do it after, as you are up to date (short of an update coming out).  The problems I had were around not being able to sync-tools during bootstrap, because my cluster didn't have external access.  My work around to do what IO alluded to in my first answer.
What happens if you don't specify the source?